# Is it true that $E_{\theta} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p_{\theta} (X) \right ) = 0$?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, fisher-information

In a statistics book I found the following definition for the Fisher information:
$$I_{\theta} := \text{var} _{\theta} \left ( \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}  \log p_{\theta} (X)\right ), $$ where $X$ is a random variable that is distributed according to the density $p_{\theta}$. However, I also know the definition
$$I_{\theta} := E _{\theta} \left ( \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p_{\theta} (X)\right ) ^2 \right ), $$
so I suspect that
$$E _{\theta} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p_{\theta} (X) \right ) = 0,$$
but I am not fully confident about it and I also do not know how to proceed if I want to prove this.

I have been thinking about the following. Write out
$$E _{\theta} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p_{\theta} (X) \right ) = \int p_{\theta} (x)  \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p_{\theta} (x) \ dx.$$
Then use one of the following integration techniques: do a change of variables (maybe $y=p_{\theta} (x)$?) or use the method of integration by parts.

Does someone know more about this? A reference to an article, book, or website is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the answer in another statistics book! We have:
\begin{align*}
E _{\theta} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta } \log p_{\theta} (X) \right ) & = E _{\theta} \left ( \frac{1}{p_{\theta} (X) } \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} p_{\theta} (X) \right ) \\
& = \int p_{\theta} (x) \frac{1}{p_{\theta} (x) } \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} p_{\theta} (x) dx \\
& = \int \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} p_{\theta} (x) dx \\
& = \frac{d}{d\theta} \int p_{\theta} (x) dx \\
& = \frac{d}{d\theta} 1 \\
& = 0.
\end{align*}
If someone wants to delete this question, then that is ok.